# There are many ways to say "from now on,..." or "After this...' or etc, but actually which expressions are more commonly used in everyday English?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

As far as l can gather, there are there are many ways to say "from here on,..." or "After this..." or etc, but actually what expressions are more commonly used in everyday English?

> **Hereinafter**/**hereafter**:
>
> e.g. Elizabeth Gaskell's novel "Ruth" will ***hereafter*** be cited within the text as EG.
>
> **from now on/as from now**:
>
> e.g. ***From now on*** the gates will be locked at midnight
>
> **Henceforth**:
>
> e.g. ***Henceforth***, said building shall be the property of Brendan Duggan.

...

If there are some other common expressions (that I didn't mention), please tell me.

And also If you mentioned two expressions like X and Y, please specify that:
In written/spoken English, people often prefer to use X rather than Y.

Comment: Written/spoken, formal/informal/slang? Usage will vary. For example, I doubt someone would say *henceforth* to friends in casual conversation.

Comment: Don't use "**the** said": no article is necessary or desired, as *said* is a determiner here. You wouldn't say "The **this** building," would you? Try "Henceforth, said building shall be ..."

Comment: @Robusto "the said building" could mean "the aforementioned building" in addition to "said building".

Comment: @user: nope. You'd still drop the article in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In "everyday" English (by which I assume you mean *informal*, that is, they type of loose language used, for example, when speaking to friends) expressions such as "from now on", "from here on out", and "after this" are more commonly used in general.

"Henceforth" and "Hereafter" examples of a more *formal* expression, generally more archaic in nature, such as that used in a court of law or academic publishing. Most people do not use formal language outside of formal situations.